# Drupal 7 sum grouped fields

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

Help solve the problem. It is impossible to produce the amount of the grouped fields. I can only add up all the fields. What I want to get the show on the link below.

http://habrastorage.org/files/99c/5df/f1f/99c5dff1f34e4d1a9e51e3769a65b18f.png

PS Sorry for my English, I use translate.google.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help with something like this, it would be good to see a code snippet which you are using. This would give an idea of where the data is coming from and what format the data is.

Comment: I produce grouping standard means. Grouped by fields "people", "date". I need to find the sum of the fields "time" and display it in the "count". Additional code I don't wrote.

Comment: Can you provide the name of the module or something similar?

Comment: I created the type of material "tasks." In which field are "people, the name, date, time, total" With views created a page "TASK". Display Mode views table. Exposed group in the fields.

Side of the module do not use.

Comment: So, you are using the drupal views module to display this data and you would like a sum of the fields within the last row. Can you export the view and paste the code within your original question please?